# What is the best way to structure the following database query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am really having trouble constructing a query that meets the following criteria.

Where the start date is today/future OR 0000/00/00
Where the end date is today/future OR 0000/00/00
Where views more than 3

Here is what I have so far.

```
$users = DB::table('videos')
    ->where('start' <= date('Y-m-d'));
    ->orwhere('start' = "0000:00:00 0000");
    ->where('end' > date('Y-m-d'));
    ->orwhere('end' = "0000:00:00 0000");
    ->where('views' => "3");
    ->get();
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks guys!

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: @Max if you're happy with my answer, you can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [advanced where](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres) with parameter grouping:

```
$users = DB::table('videos')
    ->where(function($q) {
        $q->where('start', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))
          ->orWhere('start', '=', "0000:00:00 0000");
    })
    ->where(function($q) {
        $q->where('end', '>', date('Y-m-d'))
          ->orWhere('end', '=', "0000:00:00 0000");
    })
    ->where('views', '>', 3)
    ->get();
```

Comment: This looks like it is going to do the trick! I will give it a go when I get back to work and let you know! Thanks.

Comment: Works perfectly, unfortunately I can't up vote you because I am a new user.

Comment: @MaxSangster glad to help! you can stiill accept my answer :)